# React: table not updating after editing record

Tags: reactjs

I have a React application where I'm fetching data from an API and displaying it in a table. When I add a new record and then edit the same, the changes are not get reflected in the table. I have provided code snippets because the original code is extensive and encompasses multiple functionalities. Below is the relevant code:

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate, generatePath, Link, BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import withReactContent from 'sweetalert2-react-content';
import DataTable from 'react-data-table-component';
import { useParams } from 'react-router';

function CustomerMaster() {
  
  const usernameglobal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('username'));
  const usertimestampglobal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('usertimestamp'));

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  // const usernameglobal='';
  
  const Redirectif = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
      if (usernameglobal == null) {
        navigate('/LoginPage');
      }
    }, [usernameglobal, navigate]);
  } 

  try {
    if (usertimestampglobal != null) {
      const parsedTimestamp = parseInt(usertimestampglobal, 10);
      const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
      const twelveHoursAgo = currentTime - (12 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // 12 hours in milliseconds

      if (parsedTimestamp < twelveHoursAgo) {
        localStorage.removeItem('usertimestamp');
        localStorage.removeItem('username');
        Redirectif();
      }
    }
  }
  catch {
    
  }
  
  if(usernameglobal == null){
    Redirectif();
    // return null; 
  }
  
  const [UserMasterDataGlobal, setUserMasterDataGlobal] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch data from the specified URL
    axios.get('http://localhost/api_link/codeigniter_part/public/UserMaster/getdatabyusername?username='+usernameglobal)

        .then((response) => {
          setUserMasterDataGlobal(response.data.UserMasterDataGlobal);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error('Error fetching data:', error));
  }, [usernameglobal]);

  const MySwal = withReactContent(Swal);

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    centerid: '',
    customer_mp_id: '',
    customer_centerwiseid: '',
    customer_name: '',
    customer_place: '',
    customer_mobile: '',
    routename: '',
    customer_status: '',
    customer_type: '',
    servicecharges: '',
    opbal: '',
    clbal: '',
    operationtype: 'Add Customer',
    customer_mp_id_hidden: '',
  });

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };
  
  
  const [CustomerMasterData, setCustomerMasterData] = useState([]);
  //2) using axios
  useEffect(() => {
  // Fetch data from the specified URL
    if (UserMasterDataGlobal.length > 0) {

      if(UserMasterDataGlobal?.[0]?.usertype  !== "ADMIN" &&  UserMasterDataGlobal?.[0]?.usertype !== "DAIRY OWNER"){
        var urllink='http://localhost/api_link/codeigniter_part/public/CustomerMaster?CompanyId='+UserMasterDataGlobal?.[0]?.CompanyId+'&centerid='+UserMasterDataGlobal?.[0]?.centerid;
      } else {
        var urllink='http://localhost/api_link/codeigniter_part/public/CustomerMaster?CompanyId='+UserMasterDataGlobal?.[0]?.CompanyId;
      }

      axios.get(urllink)
        .then((response) => {
          // Access the response data directly using response.data
          setCustomerMasterData(response.data.CustomerMasterData);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error('Error fetching data:', error));
    }
  }, [UserMasterDataGlobal]);
  
  
   const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(event.target);
    
    if(Object.keys(validationerrors).length == 0) {
      // alert('no validation message');
      // return;
      var data = {
        CompanyId: UserMasterDataGlobal?.[0]?.CompanyId,
        userid: UserMasterDataGlobal?.[0]?.userid,
        centerid: centerid1,
        customer_name: formData.get('customer_name').trim(),
        customer_centerwiseid: formData.get('customer_centerwiseid').trim(),
        customer_place: formData.get('customer_place'),
        routename: formData.get('routename'),
        customer_mobile: formData.get('customer_mobile').trim(),
        customer_type: formData.get('customer_type'),
        opbal: formData.get('opbal').trim(),
        servicecharges: formData.get('servicecharges').trim(),
        customer_status: formData.get('customer_status'),
        operationtype: formData.get('operationtype'),
        customer_mp_id: formData.get('customer_mp_id_hidden')
      };

     const response = await axios.post('http://localhost/api_link/codeigniter_part/public/CustomerMaster/update', data);
        
        if (response.status === 200) {
          // The data was successfully saved
          // You can display a success message to the user
              if(response.data.message == "Sucesss"){
                  MySwal.fire({
                  //   title: <strong>Record Saved Sucessfully!</strong>,
                  html: <b>Record updated Sucessfully!</b>,
                  icon: 'success'
                  })
                  data.clbal = response.data.clbal;
                  setCustomerMasterData((prevData) => {
                    const updatedData = [...prevData];
                    const index = updatedData.findIndex((record) => record.customer_mp_id === data.customer_mp_id);
                    
                    if (index !== -1) {
                      updatedData[index] = { ...updatedData[index], ...data };
                    }                  
                    return updatedData;
                  });
    
              } else if (response.data==="ccwname_present"){
                
                MySwal.fire({ 
                //   title: <strong>Record Saved Sucessfully!</strong>,
                  html: <b>  This Customer name already present. can't save this record...</b>,
                  icon: 'warning'
                })
              
              }

          } else {
            // There was an error saving the data
            // You can display an error message to the user
            // console.log(response);
          }
      }
      
    function getdatabyrecordarray(record) {

    setdefaultcityname(record.customer_place);
    setdefaultcenter(record.centerid);
    setdefaultroutename(record.routename);

    setFormData({
      centerid: record.centerid,
      customer_mp_id: record.customer_mp_id,
      customer_centerwiseid: record.customer_centerwiseid,
      customer_name: record.customer_name,
      centerName: record.customer_place,
      customer_place: record.customer_place,
      customer_mobile: record.customer_mobile,
      customer_type: record.customer_type,
      routename: record.routename,
      opbal: record.opbal,
      clbal: record.clbal,
      servicecharges: record.servicecharges,
      customer_status: record.customer_status,
      operationtype: 'Edit Customer'
    });
    // following code is to go to top of the page after clicking on edit button.
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
  }
  
  
  onst [defaultcityname, setdefaultcityname] = useState();
  const [defaultroutename, setdefaultroutename] = useState();
  const [defaultcenter, setdefaultcenter] = useState();
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const recordsPerPage = 5;
  const lastIndex = currentPage * recordsPerPage;
  const firstIndex = lastIndex - recordsPerPage;
  const records = CustomerMasterData.slice(firstIndex, lastIndex);
  const npage = Math.ceil(CustomerMasterData.length / recordsPerPage);
  //const numbers = [...Array(npage + 1).keys()].slice(1);
  const getVisiblePageNumbers = (currentPage, totalPages) => {
    // Handle cases with 5 or fewer pages
    if (totalPages <= 5) {
      return [...Array(totalPages + 1).keys()].slice(1);
    }
  
    // Handle cases with more than 5 pages
    const visiblePages = [1, 2, currentPage, totalPages - 1, totalPages];
    let gap = false;
    const finalNumbers = [];
  
    for (let i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
      if (visiblePages.includes(i)) {
        finalNumbers.push(i);
        gap = false;
      } else if (!gap) {
        finalNumbers.push('...');
        gap = true;
      }
    }
  
    return finalNumbers;
  };
  
  const numbers = getVisiblePageNumbers(currentPage, npage);

  function navigatetologin() {
    localStorage.removeItem('usertimestamp');
    localStorage.removeItem('username');
    navigate('/loginpage');
  }

  function getclbalvalue() {
    if(formData.operationtype != "Edit Customer") {
      setFormData({
        ...formData,
        clbal: formData.opbal,
      })
    }
  }

  return (

    <div className="container" style={{color: '#4229cb', fontWeight: '500' ,backgroundColor: 'rgb(255 255 255)'}} >
    <h1 style={{ color: 'white', backgroundColor: '#4229cb', padding: '5px' }} className="text-center"> Customer Master</h1>
      <nav style={{ marginTop: -8, marginBottom: 18 }} className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">Home</a>
          <ul className="navbar-nav">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <span className="nav-link" style={{cursor: 'default'}}>{`Welcome ${UserMasterDataGlobal?.[0]?.username}`}</span>
              </li>
          </ul>
          <a className="navbar-brand" onClick={navigatetologin} style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}>Log out</a>
        </div>
      </nav>

    <div className="row" styles={{backgroundColor: 'lightgreen'}}>
      <div className="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} method="POST" id="form1">
        
        //input form
        
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div className="row mt-4">
      <div className="col-md-12 table-responsive-xl">
        <table className="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>CenterName</th>
              <th>Route</th>
              <th>Place</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {records.map((c, index) => (
            <tr key={c.customer_mp_id}>
              <td>{c.customer_centerwiseid}</td>
              <td>{c.customer_name}</td>
              <td>{getCenterNameById(c.centerid)}</td>
              <td>{c.routename}</td>
              <td>{c.customer_place}</td>
              <td>
                <button onClick={() => getdatabyrecordarray(c)} className="btn btn-info btn-sm">Edit</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        
        <nav style={{float: 'right' }}>
          <ul className='pagination'>
              <li className='page-item'>
                <a href='#' className='page-link'
                onClick={prePage}>Prev</a>
              </li>

              {/* {
                numbers.map((n, i) => (
                  <li className={`page-item ${currentPage === n ? 'active' : ''}`} key={i}>
                    <a href='#' className='page-link'
                    onClick={() => ChangeCpage(n)}>{n}</a>
                  </li>
                ))
              } */}
              
              {
                numbers.map((n, i) => (
                <li className={`page-item ${currentPage === n ? 'active' : ''}`} key={i}>
                  {n === '...' ? (
                    <span className="page-link disabled">...</span>
                  ) : (
                    <a href="#" className="page-link" onClick={() => ChangeCpage(n)}>
                      {n}
                    </a>
                  )}
                </li>
              ))}

              <li className='page-item'>
                <a href='#' className='page-link'
                onClick={nextPage}>Next</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  );

  function prePage() {
    if(currentPage !== 1) {
      setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1)
    }
  }

  function ChangeCpage(id) {
    setCurrentPage(id)
  }

  function nextPage() {
    if(currentPage !== npage) {
      setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1)
    }
  }

}

export default CustomerMaster;
```

Can someone help me understand why the changes made after editing a record, which was just added, are not reflected in the HTML table, and how to fix it?

Comment: Where are you updating the record in your provided code? Where is ConfirmDelete function ?
Where is getdatabyrecordarray function?
Most important to call api again after editing is checking for update in UserMasterDataGlobal, where is that ? How you are  using UserMasterDataGlobal? 
Your question is not clear please look into it. 
The most important your are using useEffect with UserMasterDataGlobal which is responsible for fetching data again when you update the record. Please take a look into it. Thank you !

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I have updated my code in the previous question. I have now pasted a detailed code that should be self-explanatory. Please review it and let me know if you have any questions or concerns.

Comment: I think you should first console each step in setCustomerMasterData() while updating .
is code is passing through it or not ??
And as suggested use loose type comparison.

Answer (score 0):

When updating the customermasterdata array after an update operation, there was an issue with the comparison of record.customer_mp_id and data.customer_mp_id using the strict equality operator ===. This operator not only compares values but also checks for matching data types. Consequently, when adding a record and subsequently editing it, the data types might not match, resulting in a failed comparison and the index value being set to -1. As a consequence, the state of the customermasterdata array wasn't updating correctly.

Recognizing this issue, I investigated the code and realized that changing the comparison from strict equality (===) to loose equality (==) could resolve the problem. Here's the updated code snippet:

```
setCustomerMasterData((prevData) => {
    const updatedData = [...prevData];
    const index = updatedData.findIndex((record) => record.customer_mp_id == data.customer_mp_id);

    if (index !== -1) {
        updatedData[index] = { ...updatedData[index], ...data };
    }           

    return updatedData;
});
```

By employing loose equality (==), the comparison now considers only the values without considering their data types. This adjustment ensured that when adding a new customer and subsequently editing it, the customermasterdata array gets properly updated both in the HTML table and within the array itself.